# What sort of challenges can one expect to see after choosing to become a full time learner if starting out later in life?

Tags: torah-study, how-to, adult-learning, kollel

If one started out his life pursuing a career how difficult would it be for him to switch gears and enroll in a kollel or yeshivah to become a full time torah learner?

What sort of options are available in regards to making a living?

How can one know if it's right for him?

Does it make a difference if his level is not as advanced as someone who went to kollel straight after yeshivah without any breaks?

What can he expect to experience after beginning such a transition?

Comment: Unless you add some objective measures of assessment, I think this is primarily opinion based.

Comment: YeZ, would help to change the title from "how difficult" to "what can one expect"?

Comment: are there too many variables to make this answerable?

Comment: That's a little better.  You could focus it on what challenges he can expect.

Comment: This would depend on whether the person had a solid Yeshiva education prior to embarking on a career. Whether the person kept learning while he had a career. It would depend on one's standard of living. It would depend on whether money was put away during the years one had a career. I think the variables are immense and this question is truly unanswerable.

Comment: @YeZ, et al, unless I missed a major revision within the 5-minute opening window, this looks like a decent question to me. It focuses a lot more on lifestyle than most of our questions, but I think it's within scope and answerable.

Comment: Rabbi Akiva was 40 years old and never learned Torah. Once he saw a rock with a hole carved into it by water dripping on it daily. He said, "If something soft can penetrate something hard, surely Torah, which is hard as iron, can penetrate a heart of flesh and blood." He immediately went to study Torah with his son in a class for schoolchildren. He began by learning the alphabet, and after 13 years he was teaching Torah to the masses. ([*Avos d'Rabbi Nassan* 6:2](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/mahshevt/avot/6-2.htm))

Comment: @SethJ My main objection is that "how hard is X" is subjective.  You may think that juggling is _really_ hard, while I think that juggling is very easy.  I was just looking for something objectively measurable.

Comment: I think this is a good set of questions, but wonder if it should be broken up.  "What programs are out there for this type of learner", "what can he expect", and "how does he know if it's right for him" should probably be separate questions, no?

Comment: @fred that is at the same time the most incredible and ridiculous story. A rock with a hole in it?? I don't think any kiruv organization has tried that trick (but I'd imagine the results wouldn't be so great)

Comment: @Matt [Weathering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weathering).

Comment: YeZ, with issues such as this one personal experience and opinions can aid a person in his decision.

Comment: @YeZ, I understand, but, "How difficult is it to..." can also be understood as a casual way of asking, "How can somebody...and what obstacles can fall in their path that they should be aware of?" And, in that regard, "How difficult is it to..." is both more open-ended than that formulation, and easier to answer (potentially). Because if someone says, "What challenges are there..." it doesn't quite invite the positive side, which can be drawn out of "How difficult is it to..." You can always say, "There are challenges X, Y, and Z, but it's worth it" ...

Comment: @YeZ ... but with "How difficult is it to..." there's more of a natural segue in the question for the positive spin (potentially) in the answer: "Well, you can expect problems X, Y, and Z, but frankly they don't really matter all that much because of the benefits of A, B, and C."

Comment: @YeZ, see what I mean? Or am I just rambling because I am curious about the answer(s) to the question(s)?

Comment: @SethJ I see what you mean, I am just concerned that "How difficult is it..." invites answers of the type "It's really difficult!  I tried, and it was really, _really_ hard!" or even "it isn't that difficult - just keep at it!"  As opposed to "What challenges are there" (preferably with some objective definition of a challenge) would yield more objectively measurable answers.

Comment: One more down vote and it's a close. :) I stink at asking question on MY!

Comment: YeZ, feel free to edit the question to make it more suitable for the guidelines of Mi Yodeya.